# Using pexpect similarily to subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pexpect

I am writing a script to automate a process on a remote server. The basics would look something like:

```
import pexpect

logonPrompt = '[$#] '

test = pexpect.spawn('ssh user@server')
test.expect(logonPrompt)
test.sendline('/etc/init.d/service restart')
test.expect(logonPrompt)
```

Now after the service restarts, I want to spawn a new command to drop me into a 'less' output of the service's log. Simply running test.sendline('less /logs/service/logfile') doesn't work properly.

I've done simular using the subprocess module and simply doing a subprocess.call(['less', '/logs/service/logfile')], which puts the console into the less process, and then continues when I exit that process.

Is this possible to do with pexpect? Is there a way to combine the power of the two? I need pexpect because I have to do some wizardary before restarting the service, so I can't simply do a subprocess call to ssh and run the commands.

Comment: Try sending the command you want and then doing `test.interact()`.

Comment: Yeah, this kind of works. When it send a `test.interact()` after the `test.sendline('less /logfile')` it does drop me into the less, but after qutting the less I am dropped into a shell prompt and have to exit that for the script to continue. It works as a workaround, just not ideal. Worse comes to worse I can live with this, so thank you! :)

Comment: Pexpect does not know about when less finishes, it's just transferring data between your terminal and the virtual terminal it's running ssh in.